# What is the first parameter of this db_query call for?

Tags: 6, database

I've inherited some code. It works, but I'm wondering what the "5" does in this db_query statement.

```
$result = db_query(5, "SELECT * FROM {foo} WHERE bar = '%d'", $bar_val);
```

Comment: No version of db_query takes anything other than a query string as the first parameter - if it works, I'd wager someone has altered the core function to accept that numeric parameter for whatever reason.

Comment: you're right. the previous owner hacked core and changed the function. thanks! do you want to restate your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument taken from [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_query/6.x) is the query string to execute; the next parameters are the values of the placeholders used in the query strings.

If you see code similar to the one you show, it means the content of [includes/database.mysql-common.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.mysql-common.inc/6.x), or [includes/database.pgsql.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.pgsql.inc/6.x) (depending on the database engine used) has been changed to alter the first parameter used from `db_query()`. If you are using third-party database drivers, check the `database.<database-engine>.inc` file that should come with that database driver.